# Fulfill a (possibly-void) promise

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing some multithreaded code and using promise/future to call a function on a different thread and return its result. For simplicitly, I'll remove the threading part entirely:

```
template <typename F>
auto blockingCall(F f) -> decltype(f()) 
{
    std::promise<decltype(f())> promise;

    // fulfill the promise
    promise.set_value(f());

    // block until we have a result
    return promise.get_future().get();
}
```

This works great for any function that returns non-`void`. And the return statement getting the future also works for `void`. But I can't fulfill the promise if `f` is a `void` function, because:

> promise.set_value(f()); // **error**: invalid use of void expression

Is there some clever way of setting the value in the `void` case in-line, or do I have to just write a helper function like `call_set_value(promise, f)` that has an overloads for `std::promise<R>` and `std::promise<void>`?

Comment: I don't have the template skills to do it myself, but I have a feeling you could probably SFINAE on the return type.

Comment: What exactly is the point of calling the function on another thread if you are just going to wait until the call is done? (Barring the obvious case of dispatching the call to a *specific* thread.)

Comment: Why are you using the low level promise - you might just use std::future

Comment: @cdhowie I need to call functions on a specific other thread.

Comment: @Barry Right, okay. That makes sense. Just wanted to make sure that the promise and threading code was even necessary.

Comment: @DieterLücking Explain please. I don't believe it's possible without the `promise`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `promise` is only one kind of asynchronous result provider. Instead of a `promise` you could use a `packaged_task` which wraps a callable object, similar to a `std::function` except that invoking it makes the result available via a `future` (and of course it handles the difference between `void` and non-void results):

```
template <typename F>
auto blockingCall(F f) -> decltype(f()) 
{
    std::packaged_task<decltype(f())()> task(std::move(f));

    task();

    // block until we have a result
    return task.get_future().get();
}
```

N.B. according to the current standard, this code would have a data race if `task()` and `task.get_future()` happen on separate threads (and so would your original using a promise), so you should call `get_future()` before handing the task to the other thread. In practice it should be safe on real implementations and there's a library issue ([LWG 2412](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2412)) to make it valid anyway.

Comment: Why can't I move a task into a `std::function`? e.g. `std::function<void()> func = [t = std::move(task)]() mutable { t(); };` gives an error about `task` being noncopyable.

Comment: `std::function` is copyable, so requires its target object to be copyable as well (the type of the target is type-erased, so `function` cannot be made copyable only when it wraps a copyable object, because the target can change dynamically at run-time) . `packaged_task` is move-only, so can't be stored in a `function`

Comment: Oh right! Cool. I like this solution. Also I'm glad you changed your hat from the Spock one, cause that definitely made your single-eye photo even creepier :)

Comment: N.B. if you _could_ put a `packaged_task` in a `function` the lambda would be unnecessary, you could just do `std::function<void()> f(std::move(task))`

Comment: I like the handegg hat, it looks even more like a cyclops =)

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Function overload is the cleanest solution:

```
set(promise, f);
```

then implement `set` as overloaded functions, as:

```
template<typename F, typename R>
void set(std::promise<R> & p, F && f) //handle non-void here
{
    p.set_value(f()); 
}

template<typename F>
void set(std::promise<void> & p, F && f)  //handle void here
{
    f();
    p.set_value(); 
}
```